# showModal() on dialog element doesnt work for Safari but does for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

Im having some issues presenting a modal on Safari. This currently works in Chrome:

```
var screenShotDialog = document.createElement("DIALOG");
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].appendChild(screenShotDialog);
screenShotDialog.showModal();
```

however, when i try to run this same server on Safari, this showModal() method is appending this dialog to the bottom of my page, while in Chrome it shows it as a "popup". Checking the console logs, im getting

> screenShotDialog.showModal is not a function. (In
>   'screenShotDialog.showModal()', 'screenShotDialog.showModal' is
>   undefined)

I dont get this error in chrome, looking at the dialog documentation here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_dialog_showmodal.asp I see that this should be supported for Safari ( i have Safari Version 9.0.3 ). Can anyone help this is pretty frustrating.

Comment: don't listen to fools: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog

Comment: Dammit, any alternatives you would recommend @dandavis?

Comment: bootstrap modals are well-supported and much lighter than jqui ones. picomodal is good for vanilla.

Comment: There should be a polyfill for this, but it doesn't work for me either in this case.